# Xml parsing using xml.dom

Tags: python, xml

My xmls aren't like others.
Here is an example of my xml:

```
        "<msg t='sys'><body action='verChk' r='0'><ver v='153' /></body></msg>"
```

what I want is to get the value of action.
How do I do that using xml.dom in python...

Comment: Check [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that uses xml.dom and extracts value of action attribute:

```
s = "<msg t='sys'><body action='verChk' r='0'><ver v='153' /></body></msg>"

from xml.dom import minidom

el = minidom.parseString(s)

el.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].attributes['action'].value
Out[4]: u'verChk'
```

Comment: so basically this will output 'verChk' ?

Comment: Yes, output is value of "action" attribute of "body" element.